# Is it possible to supply a selection of two positional arguments where one of the two must be selected?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I need to set a single positional argument to supply two available options, either the user can enter use the positional argument `add` or the positional argument `delete`. I would like to know how something like this is an option and hopefully a code example for how it might look.

an example of how I would expect the CLI to use this argument:
`./myscript.py add --user USERNAME`,
or
`./myscript.py delete --user USERNAME`,
or
`./myscript.py delete --database DATABASE`, etc.

Bonus points if we can somehow make this positional argument none-required

P.S. I don't mean to make the bonus question, the main question... it's much less important :)

Thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the possible values with a `choices` parameter.  And make it optional with the '?' `nargs`:

```
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo',choices=['abc','def'],nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('-d')     # flagged options 
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

The positional can occur in any order relative to the optionals.

Using more than one positional, where one is '?', is a bit trickier, see: [Python argparse, Value after positional argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54383659/python-argparse-value-after-positional-argument)

For more control over which optional is allowed with these positional values, look at the subparsers mechanism.  But for a start try this simple version.

Test with:

```
print(parser.parse_args([]))   # no input, ok
print(parser.parse_args(['-d', '1', 'abc']  # ok
parser_parse_args(['adf'])  # error
```

Comment: So, with this, will both `abc` and `def` = `foo` as the actual argument being made?

Comment: Yes, the value of `args.foo` will end up being either 'abc' or 'def'.  Attempted to provide another string will produce an argparse error.

Comment: Then I wonder if the dictionary value would be the string choice that you’ve entered in or if it would be foo... because if the dictionary value changed depending on what string choice you entered, that might actually work for me

Comment: `args` and ` vars(args)` have the same information, just different access syntax.

Comment: Okay, well after inserting a choice within my argument - `user` and `database` choices within a `--add` argument for example - could I call the choices within the argument in an if statement such as `if args.add+args.user:` for example?

Comment: Have you done a `print(args)`?  I can't help you without seeing that display.  Otherwise I'm just guessing,

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use a mutually exclusive group. From the official docs:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
>>> group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
>>> group.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
>>> group.add_argument('--bar', action='store_false')
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo'])
Namespace(bar=True, foo=True)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--bar'])
Namespace(bar=False, foo=False)
>>> parser.parse_args(['--foo', '--bar'])
usage: PROG [-h] [--foo | --bar]
PROG: error: argument --bar: not allowed with argument --foo
```